# Django Models Foreign key to same model I should not be able to add the same model in my example

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class TestToExample(models.Model):
    example1 = models.ForeignKey(Test,related_name='example1')    
    example2 = models.ForeignKey(Test,related_name='example2')
```

Here I'm Able to add example1 to Test and example 2 to Test  I should not be doing that. both example 1 & 2 should not have the same values of the Test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the model's `save()` method:

```
class TestToExample(models.Model):
    example1 = models.ForeignKey(Test,related_name='example1')    
    example2 = models.ForeignKey(Test,related_name='example2')

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, 
             using=None, update_fields=None):
        assert self.example1 != self.example2
        # Or:
        # if self.example1 == self.example2:
        #     raise WhateverError
        super(TestToExample, self).save(
            force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using, 
            update_fields=update_fields)
```

This will generally disallow you to ever have an invalid model state (with the exception of creating instances via `bulk_create()`). If you are saving instances via admin or through a model form, you might be better off overriding the model's `clean()` method and raising a `ValidationError` there (see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)) in order to provide proper error messages instead of internal server errors:

```
class TestToExample(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        if self.example1 == self.example2:
            raise ValidationError('example1 and example2 must be different')
        super(TestToExample, self).clean()
```